# Is there an implied top level parameter that is required when using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to understand how parameters require work with rails controllers.
I have a user controller to create a user. My json looks like so:

```
{
"name":"user onex",
"username":"useronea",
"email":"userone@gmail.comb",
"password":"123456",
"password_confirmation":"123456"
}
```

And my controller code looks like this

```
# POST /users
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render json: @user, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages },
           status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
def user_params
  params.permit(
    :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  )
end
```

rails lets me create this user but I do see an error in red stating

```
Unpermitted parameter: user
```

If I modify the user_params as follows (Like I've seen on other examples)

```
  params.require(:user),permit(
    :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  )
```

The rails application fails to see my email and password. I get a 403 error

I don't understand why I'm getting the unpermitted parameter 'user' when Im not sending that parameter in the first case unless its just implied.  If its implied then why doesn't the second case work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

> Also, if you've turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer
> or called wrap_parameters in your controller, you can safely omit the
> root element in the JSON parameter. In this case, the parameters will
> be cloned and wrapped with a key chosen based on your controller's
> name.
>
> - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters

[ActionController::ParamsWrapper](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) will turn:

```
{ "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" }
```

Into:

```
{ name: "acme", address: "123 Carrot Street", company: { name: "acme", address: "123 Carrot Street" } }
```

The idea is that you can use the same params whitelisting method for both flat JSON parameters and nested FormData parameters when you have controllers that serve both JSON and HTML. This is one of those ideas that hasn't aged well.

You can disable it with for your entire application with `config.wrap_parameters = false` or per controller with the `wrap_parameters false` class method.

Comment: The setting appears to be removed from Rails 7 at least so YMMV.